# Prove the set-theoretic identity for sets A and B: {2,2,2}={2}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on proofs right now. I just came across the question stated in the title. The main question I have is, does the number of elements in a set matter for equality if all elements in both sets are equal? Since 2 is a member of both sets A and B, and the only element(s) in both A and B is 2, it seems this definition of set equality would hold. Am I wrong?

Comment: Those 2 sets are indeed equal

Comment: The number of *distinct* elements in each set matters, however as you noted there is only one distinct element in each set, namely $2$, and the sets are considered equal *as sets*.  There is a generalization where you can consider them different if you look at them as *multisets*, but again they are considered the same as sets.